# Как проверить существует ли DB?

Tags: java, postgresql

Мне нужен метод проверяющий что база даных существует чтобы если вернется `false` сделать `create database ...;`

Если я создаю подключение:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/auto_services",
                        "postgres",
                        "1");
```

То я должен указать путь к базе и если ее там не окажется у меня все упадет.

Если я укажу путь до корня базы `"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432"`, то мне надо проверить есть ли она.

1. Каким запросом можно проверить существует ли база, так что-бы ответ можно было интерпретировать как true/false уже в джаве?
2. смогу ли я через обычный `Connection` использовать команду `\c my_db` чтобы попасть в подкаталог, или если я уже подключился по определенному `url` то мне только открывать новое подключение?

Comment: [`"SELECT 1 AS result FROM pg_database WHERE datname='yapab'"`](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1134045284.21190.4.camel@linux.site)

Comment: вот тут смотрите: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema

Comment: @etki спасибо это проясняет только вот что такое datname это понятно - имя искомой базы, а что надо подставить на место pg_database? Что то не понятно что он делает(((

Comment: @Rafael Osipov там все здорово но про таблицы про проверку существования баз там нет

Comment: @Павел, [The catalog pg_database stores information about the available databases.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-database.html)

Comment: @Павел информация о базах данных хранится в системных таблицах. Это, так называемая, метаинформация (metadata), вот её и рекомендуется читать и проверять. Вы делаете запрос к системной таблице СУБД, и проверяете, есть-ли в ней запись о нужной вам базе данных или нет. Если есть, то ваша база в СУБД существует.

Comment: @Rafael да pg_database вроде и есть та всезнающая таблица но когда я делаю так  select 1 as result pg_database where datname = 'auto_services';   получаю ошибку синтаксиса...

Comment: @Павел, Ну да, у Вас как минимум `from` отсутствует.

Comment: @Павел, запрос должен соответствовать синтаксису `SQL`. Вы, скорее всего пропустили то или иное ключевое слово.

Comment: @post_zeew ух е мое что-то я перегрелся пора отдыхать... спасибо большое!